# CosmosDB Query For Searching in a DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have the entries in my CosmosDB that following this structure:

```
{
    "id": "~results:123",
    "catalog:entity": [
        {
            "id": "~song.base:1da",
            "schema:name": "Autobiography",
            "schema:code": [
                "7dhs"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "~song.base:2da",
            "schema:name": "Autobiography",
            "schema:code": [
                "4lko"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However I'm having issues in getting searching for those that contain a specific `schema:code:` that in exists in an array with a parent array `catalog:entity`.

I've tried a handful of things such as with no luck:

`SELECT * FROM c JOIN schema:code IN c["catalog:entity"] WHERE schema:code IN "7dhs"`

- generally I just keep seeing `SELECT *' is only valid with a single input set.`

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any issues you met? What's the data result you want?

Comment: I want to get any documents where the `schema:code` array contains a string `7dhs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sql:

```
SELECT c FROM c 
JOIN s IN c["catalog:entity"]
where array_contains(s["schema:code"],"7dhs",false)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much - really appreciated.

Comment: One thing - say I wanted to get teh entire document back `SELECT * from c` doenst seem to work

Comment: @userMod2 Yes,same for me. You could try workaround: `select c.a,c.b,c.c,c.d.... from c`,maybe that could work.

Comment: Yep - that helps. Wonder why one can't use Select * in this case